# Hyper-V @ Windows Server 2019: VM boot fails after DDA connecting Radeon GPU

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

How can it be, that Hyper-V tells me a DDA connected GPU is already in use by another VM, if there is only one VM in the Hyper-V Manager? (Wrong error message bug?)

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? (What I'm doing wrong?)

I hop the problem is not my hardware - I'm sacraficing my gaming pc for my Windows Server experiments. => It's only "cheap" consumer hardware.

Not sure, if a german error message will help, but here it is:
[German error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdLG6.jpg)
(My rough translation: The Plug & Play PCIe device cannot be assigned, because it's already in use by another VM)

Others with the same problem and parts of the error msg in english: [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a556653-88e0-4f98-a6d2-aa55f033546a/win-server-2016-v1709-element-not-found-when-starting-vms-with-passthrough-gpus?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv)

The tutorial I followed: [blog.workinghardinit.work](https://blog.workinghardinit.work/2016/04/11/discrete-device-assignment-in-windows-server-2016-hyper-v/)

My system:

- Clean installed Windows Server 2019 (Standard; I belive, or what ever the version is, that Microsoft hands out to students for free via their "Azure for Education" program)
- With GUI, the Hyper-V role as well as some parts of SMB file sharing
- AMD Ryzen CPU
- AMD Radeon graphics card

Comment: Please check the steps here: https://lenovopress.com/lp0088.pdf

Comment: @Overmind As far as I can tell, these are the same steps in the tutorial I linked above, just without a lot of the clarification.

Comment: My suspicion was that your GPU was not unassigned completely from the host, therefore will not be DDA'able in the guest.

Comment: I did check using `Get-VMHostAssignableDevice` and the GPU is in the first step disabled in the device manager and later completely removed from the graphic card section

Comment: Have you tried returning the GPU to host and then repeating the procedure ? You should try that but restart the host after both add and removal.

Comment: I tried that now, but it changed nothing.